# How to make prettier autoformatter in VScode not remove commas from typescript types after I added React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

When I save a file with autoformatter on, the type

```
type Params = {
  fileName: string,
  isTxt: boolean
}
```

will be saved as

```
type Params = {
  fileName: string
  isTxt: boolean
}
```

Which React no longer accepts. Prettier only started deleting the commas after I added React to the project. How do I make prettier not do that?

I am using Prettier extension v9.0.0 and Typescript v4.5.2 in VScode 1.62.3.

Using `.prettierrc`

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "trailingComma": "none",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 80
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `trailingComma` to `all`

Comment: Even if I wanted a trailing comma - it doesn't work.

Comment: You should correct name of prettier config file. current name is pretterc and change it to `.prettierrc` @MilanSmolík

Comment: The file is named correctly, I misspelled it in the question. I will update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this should be React related. But from my test in a non-React project, `Prettier` formats both `.ts` and `.tsx` files the same way when you explicitly set [`semi`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#semicolons) to `false`, as you have.

```js
type Params = {
  fileName: string
  isTxt: boolean
}
```

And when [`semi`](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#semicolons) is `true`:

```js
type Params = {
  fileName: string;
  isTxt: boolean;
}
```

As of now (2023), they are both valid `TypeScript`. Either way, no commas are kept. This is the opinionated result from `Prettier`. It's been discussed, changed, and discussed again. This [Prettier issue in github](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1944) pretty much sums it up.

### Alternative

If you really want to keep the commas, you might need to search for another extension. `Beautify` might be another keyword for your search, but be warned that the one with the exact name has been deprecated for quite some time.

- [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) (9.8M download, **deprecated**)

Please make sure you test it thoroughly before use.